# Android tablayout tabs with viewpager in toolbar in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, landscape, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout and a view pager. In portrait mode I want tabs to appear below toolbar but in landscape mode I want tabs to appear in toolbar like this screenshot:

What I want
[image: What I want]

What I have
[image: What I have]

There are two tabs Recorder and Player. Before it was fine but after I added landscape layout it became like this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<String> filenamesarraylist;
ArrayList<String> arrPackage;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FileObserverService.class);
    startService(intent);

    // Standard tabbed navigation setup.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // ...
    // Create tabs, fragments, pager and anything else needed.
    // ...



    //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    forceTabs(); // Force tabs when activity starts.
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (position == 0) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });




}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    forceTabs(); // Handle orientation changes.
}

// This is where the magic happens!
public void forceTabs() {
    try {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        final Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
    }
    catch(final Exception e) {
        // Handle issues as needed: log, warn user, fallback etc
        // This error is safe to ignore, standard tabs will appear.
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new RecordFragment(), "RECORDER");
    adapter.addFragment(new ListenFragment(), "PLAYER");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
}
```

Theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.awesome_tabbed_layout);

        // Standard tabbed navigation setup.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // ...
        // Create tabs, fragments, pager and anything else needed.
        // ...

        forceTabs(); // Force tabs when activity starts.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration config) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
        forceTabs(); // Handle orientation changes.
    }

    // This is where the magic happens!
    public void forceTabs() {
        try {
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            final Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
            setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
        }
        catch(final Exception e) {
            // Handle issues as needed: log, warn user, fallback etc
            // This error is safe to ignore, standard tabs will appear.
        }
    }

}
```

output:

portrait mode:
[image]

Landscape mode:
[image]

Comment: please check MainActivity code i edited in question. I am using toolbar. I tried using forcetab() code but did not work

Comment: after uncommenting I get this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: did u use a `NO_ACTION_BAR` theme for ur activity?

Comment: I have used Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for this activity

Comment: comment this lines `toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`  and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: did that getting this:   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: I changed the theme and it resolved the error but landscape mode is now like this with more space added between actionbar and tabs (see above).

Comment: QUESTION: I want the portrait mode above to be exactly like the landscape mode, i.e. with all "bar elements" always on one line only. Is this at all possible? Thanks beforehand.